# How to balance load in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, elassandra

I'm using Elassandra 6.2.3
I have set a cluster of 3 nodes and created a keyspace with replication factor of 2.

I'm using `Murmur3Partitioner` and `num_tokens=8` in Cassandra configuration.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '2'} AND durable_writes = true;

DESC mykeyspace;
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable(
    f1 text,
    f2 timestamp,
    f3 text,
    f4 text,
    f5 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (f1, f2)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (f2 DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX elastic_mytable_idx ON mykeyspace.mytable () USING 'org.elassandra.index.ExtendedElasticSecondaryIndex';
```

here the ring:

```
$ nodetool ring mykeyspace

Datacenter: DC1
==========
Address    Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                          8046893569169204194
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              -7885825037800730315
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              -7261086042602187969
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              -7247943966600989463
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              -7228717159480176131
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              -6939207504674930480
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              -6158757762234956967
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              -4699623277895141955
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              -4269715227726417275
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              -3148156422280710025
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              -2567971232125784764
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              -2187229040967677675
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              -2058807466377445130
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              -1181919914747129817
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              695306942662545127
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              1989050017548537421
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              2881433693910708029
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              3454959670543032324
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              3833350227892101457
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              4855735318033934682
10.8.0.6   r1          Up     Normal  30.77 GiB       86.15%              6288034337780481749
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              6495870875989416002
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              6853344637592889364
10.8.0.14  r1          Up     Normal  7.36 GiB        49.61%              6911496393497851249
10.8.0.1   r1          Up     Normal  17.55 GiB       64.24%              8046893569169204194
```

I have created a testing program that generates 1M of random data and send them to Cassandra via nodejs's cassandra-driver library.
The testing program generates data with roughly 2900 different partition keys (f1) and different clustering keys (f2).

The result is that data are distributed like this:

```
$ nodetool status mykeyspace
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.8.0.14  12.47 GiB  8            49.6%             c5a17dbd-40ef-4f58-b132-0d977a92f1a1  r1
UN  10.8.0.1   17.55 GiB  8            64.2%             f088d009-bd97-4e35-9f20-60006a68b363  r1
UN  10.8.0.6   33.49 GiB  8            86.1%             e82191ad-9d9f-459f-9da0-2b0457ad6611  r1
```

Why does one node have almost the double of the load of the other 2 nodes?

Thanks

Comment: If you drop datas an insert it again do you have the same result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cassandra, vnodes tokens are allocated randomly, therefore the resulting token ranges may differ in size.

In practice, this effect is mitigated by the number of tokens being high.
If you want a better distribution, you could set the `num_token` to 256.

But there is a drawback, setting a high number of tokens will increase the complexity of search requests in Elassandra, because the token range is used to filter out duplicate results. See [Elassandra search path documentation](https://elassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture.html#search-path) for more information.

I would recommend not settings a `num_token` higher than 16, and ideally to benchmark different settings to fit your specific needs.